# foreach to linq

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть цикл, который ищет ближайшие совпадения по введённому слову в словаре (словарь чуть больше 1 500 000 слов) и добавляет эти слова в словарь (_searchResult) под уникальным guid. Сам Parallel.ForEach я не очень люблю (несмотря на то, что он увеличивает скорость обработки в 3-4 раза), поэтому пытаюсь найти альтернативу в linq (результаты тестов: foreach - около 3-4 секунд. Parallel.ForEach - 0,5-1 секунда). Собсна, сам Parallel.ForEach код, который хочу переписать (при возможности улучшить):

```
int matchOriginal = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(Words, (word) =>
                {
                    if (word is not null)
                    {
                        matchOriginal = LevenshteinDistanceExtensions.LevenshteinDistance(searchWord, word );
                        if (matchOriginal < 3)
                            _searchResult.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), new Product(resultInt, word));
                    }
                });
```

И вот я начал linq писать. Но я получаю тут только лист с числами, которые меньше 3, а мне нужно всё это запихнуть в словарь, в котором к тому же ещё и будет само слово, которое нашлось:

```
var linq = Words
                .Where(word => word is not null)
                .Select(word => LevenshteinDistanceExtensions.LevenshteinDistance(searchWord, word ))
                .Where(matchOriginal => matchOriginal < 3);
```

И как-бы да, я получаю лист с числами, которые меньше 3, но мне нужно всё это дело добавлять ещё в searchResult словарь.
_searchResult - Dictionary<Guid, Word>, где Word - Int ("схожесть" с оригиналом) и Name

Куда стоит копнуть, чтоб допилить этот linq (если ещё и сделать его быстрым, то вообще идеально, а не как в обычном foreach по 3-4 секунды....)

Comment: `Words.AsParallel().Where(...).Select(...).Where(...).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value)` ? См [ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel?view=net-6.0)

Comment: хотите быстрее - добавьте AsParallel, еще быстрее - допишите отсечку по максимальному расстоянию - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3866249/1988244

Comment: Совершенно вылетело ToDictionary из головы. Чуть поменял возвращаемый тип, добавил отсечку и очень прекрасного стало работать. Спасибо

Comment: Единственное, меня смущает Asparallel. Насколько я помню, он делит коллекцию на несколько (количество можно задать) и обрабатывает каждую в отдельном потоке. А что, если все потоки будут заняты? Что, если время на обработку одной коллекции будут больше, чем другой. Очень много подводных камней, с которыми страшно столкнуться. Не хотелось-бы, чтоб обычный поиск заставил зависнуть всё приложение